# Clock offset after synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization, clock

I'm trying to synchronize my system clock with NTP or some other equivalent time source, like "tick.usno.navy.mil".  I start by using the Windows Internet Time Settings and using the "Synchronize with Internet time server" update.  Then, I try to verify by pinging the same server with this code in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient();
        client.open();
        // use host name or IP address of target NTP server
        InetAddress hostAddr = InetAddress.getByName("tick.usno.navy.mil");
        TimeInfo info = client.getTime(hostAddr);
        info.computeDetails(); // compute offset/delay if not already done
        Long offsetValue = info.getOffset();
        Long delayValue = info.getDelay();
        String delay = (delayValue == null) ? "N/A" : delayValue.toString();
        String offset = (offsetValue == null) ? "N/A" : offsetValue.toString();

        System.out.println(" Roundtrip delay(ms)=" + delay
                        + ", clock offset(ms)=" + offset); // offset in ms

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Inevitably, I get a result like:

```
Roundtrip delay(ms)=47, clock offset(ms)=-441
```

So, why am I getting a clock offset immediately after I've synchronized?  The offset amount is fairly consistent after each internet sync, so I'm inclined to believe that my computer has a +/-1 second error when it synchronizes?  Is this true?  Is there something else going on?